# memory copy dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, arrays, performance, sorting, dynamic

I am currently found out a interesting and simple sorting algorithm, so I implemented it in with dynamically allocated array.
Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void positiveIntSort(int *array,int size);
void printArray(int array[],int size);

int main() {
    int bigNum = 99999;
    int *array = (int *) malloc (bigNum*sizeof(int));
    int i,index,size;
    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("Enter each element for array: ");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&index);
        array[index] = 1;
    }
    positiveIntSort(array,size);
    printArray(array,size);
}

int positiveIntSort(int *array,int size) {
    int i,j = 0;
    int sortedArray[size];
    for(i = 0; i < 99999,j < size; i++) {
        if(array[i] == 1)
            sortedArray[j++] = i;
    }
    memcpy(array,sortedArray,size);
    printArray(sortedArray,size);
}

void printArray(int array[],int size) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d\t",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

So, basically what I am doing is if user input a number : a, I go to corresponding index, which is `a` in this case, and assign `1` to this `array[a]`.
So I traverse again and print all the index with value `1`. This way gives me a sorted array.

However, I have some trouble with the dynamically allocated array.
Here is a sample output I have:

```
Enter the size of array: 5
Enter each element for array:23 12 45 63 38
12       23      38      45     63
12       1845015 0       0      0
```

So sorting is definitely working. However when I return the sorted array to the dynamically allocated array, the result messed up. I could not find the reason? Is the way I use memcpy incorrect?

Besides, is the complexity of this algorithm O(n). Is there anyway to make this algorithm better?

Comment: What's the point of the dynamic allocation here? Also providing at least the *name* of the algorithm (let alone the description) would be appropriate.

Comment: You never initialized any of the elements that the user didn't enter. Some of them might contain `1`.

Comment: You need to `memcpy(..., sizeof(int) * size)`

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You have not checked that the input value `index` is within the bounds of the array, and if it is, any other element not specifically set to `1` has an indeterminate value, since `malloc` does not initialise the memory allocated. You should also allocate the memory *after* you input the number of elements `size`, so `bigNum` is irrelevant. Moreover what is the magic number for in `i < 99999`? Did you intend `i < bigNum` (although not in scope)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I have some trouble with the dynamically allocated array.

In your code you have allocated room for the array :

```
   int *array = (int *) malloc (bigNum*sizeof(int));
```

with  exactly this many bytes:  `bigNum * sizeof(int)`.

*(BTW: There is no need to cast result of `malloc` in C language. It is recommended to check if allocation was successful and non `NULL` result of `malloc` was returned.)*

Instead of dynamically allocating the `array` (you forgot to `free` the `array` memory) you could declare it after obtaining the size of the array:

```
   //int *array = (int *) malloc (bigNum*sizeof(int));
   int i,index,size,bigNum;
   printf("Enter the size of array: ");
   scanf("%d",&bigNum );
   int array[bigNum];
   printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
   scanf("%d",&size);
```

This also problem what to do with uninitialized array elements.

Symmetrically in `int positiveIntSort(int *array,int size){`

you have to copy all the bytes belonging to the `array`. The number of bytes in this `array` is equal to number or array elements times the size of the element. In your case the size of the element if equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Therefore the line

```
   memcpy(array,sortedArray,size);
```

should be replaced by:

```
   memcpy(array,sortedArray,size* sizeof(int));
```

I will not comment on the logic of the your algorithm which does not seem to handle duplicates and negative values.

Different sorting algorithms have different time complexities:

- [Time Complexities of all Sorting Algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/).
- [Best, worst and average case - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case)

If you need faster sorting time than yours you may consider other algorithms.

Comment: You do realize how that algorithm works, right? `array` is not supposed to store the input data in a sequential way. It's size is not `size`, it is supposed to be at least as big as the largest input value, as it uses values as array indices in order to sort. So, `int array[size];` is not correct.

Comment: @KyrSt  Thanks! You are right! I should say `int array[bigNum];` Correcting.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `size` argument in `memcpy()` call inside `positiveIntSort`.
It should be:

```
memcpy(array,sortedArray,size*sizeof(int));
```

As `memcpy()` needs as a third argument the number of bytes for copying (not the number of elements of the array).

Also note that you have conflicting types of `positiveIntSort()` with one returning `void` and the other `int`, which is also ignored by the implementation.

Now about making the algorithm better:

1. There is no need for arbitrary size on your array. (or else: arbitrary max value). Store the user input in a temp array and find the maximum and minimum values . Then allocate space for (max-min+1) integers in `array`. And for each value `d`, insert it in the `d-min` position of the array. You will need an extra loop but the time complexity remains O(n) (*) and not only you don't have unnecessary constrains, but also you can decrease the memory overhead.
2. What about duplicate input values? Right now your algorithm cannot handle duplicates. You could just *add* 1 to the corresponding cell of your initial array instead of *setting to* 1 for each number. This way, if you put some extra effort in your sorting function you can locate and sort correctly all duplicates.
3. What about negative values? A way would be to perform two different sortings (one for negatives and one for positives) and concatenate them at the end (even better if you do it in place).

Finally, as it is mentioned in the comments, you also need to initialize your values in the array, as some could be 1 (use `calloc()` to make your life easier).

(*): To be exact your complexity is now Θ(max{n, nmax-nmin}), where nmax and nmin are the largest and smallest values of your input. (or the size of your array, as you will loop through it)